# Issue getting exit code from jar

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have made a jar file which takes as parameter a string representing the path to an image file. After that I made a batch file which takes a string (path to a folder full of pictures), as a parameter. Then it starts the jar file in a loop giving to it the image files. The Problem is that it should return the errorlevel form the jar, yet it returns only 0. this is the batch file:

```
set arg1=%1
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (%arg1%\*.*) do (java -jar %~dp0DrawingLinesBytedeco.jar "%%i" 
set exitcode=%ERRORLEVEL%
call echo exit code %exitcode%)
```

And this is a part of the java code:

```
if(horizontal > vertical) {
        System.out.println("The Image is horizontal");
        System.out.println("The Image is ok");
    }
else {
        System.out.println("The Image is vertical");
        System.out.println("The Image should turn");
        System.exit(1);
     }
```

This is the output I get when I run it in the console
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
set arg1=%1
goto MAIN

:JAVA
java -jar %~dp0DrawingLinesBytedeco.jar %1
set exitcode=%ERRORLEVEL%
call echo exit code %exitcode%
goto :EOF

:MAIN
for %%i in (%arg1%\*.*) do call :JAVA "%%i"
```

Comment: Thanks, It works perfectly. Can you please explain it :)

Comment: The variable %ERRORLEVEL% in the commands enclosed in parentheses in your batch file will be replaced with zero before executing the java command.